# Parse Float and Fixed(0)

Tags: reactjs, parsefloat

I have this code in react-native

```
 <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12} style={{textAlign:isRTL==='rtl'?'right':'left'}}>
        <Typography color={'primary'} style={{fontSize:30}}>
          {t('total')} - {settings?settings.symbol:null} {estimatedata.estimate ? estimatedata.estimate.estimateFare : null}
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
```

and what I want to do with is that, I want to output a fair estimate without decimals and also round it up to the nearest 10s

For example, if the price is 1458.10 first I want the 2 decimals gone and also I want the new price to be 1460.

So by putting `.fixed{0}` breaks the code for me.

Please how can I do it?

In the other part of the code. As a second question, I am able to make this work `parseFloat(estimate.estimateFare).toFixed(0)` but the problem is that it doesn't round up how I want although decimals disappear.

1564 to 1560 or 1780 to 1800

Comment: `.fixed{0}` - that's not valid as JS _or_ JSX syntax, so it shouldn't be a surprise that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

check this site maybe this is something you are looking for
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil
the round10 function they mentioned there is something you might be looking for